# Kruskal-Wallis nonparametric test for percentage data?

Tags: kruskal-wallis-test, percentage

My study design includes: 4 groups of 6 observations per group. I have short and long survival group, each time 6 control “surrounding lung “tissues and 6 lung tumor tissues.

My first question would be   tumor vs. control changes in both groups?
My second question: long versus short survival changes in tumor and “surrounding/ control “ tissue?

I did binary GLM and then posthoc correction for pairwise comparisons.

My data are independent numerical variables –quantitative measure of metabolic enzymes. The enzymes have two quantitative data: the abundances (i.e. my data matrx 1) and functional activities (my data matrix 2).

So for first data set I am using  lm . abundance data are normally distributed,
For the second data I am using GLM with quasibinomial distribution, since data are like percentages (e.g. 0, 0.2, 0.35, 0.75, 0.05..)

What would be alternative to check for differential changes?
ANOVA test for abundance data1   and  Kruskal-Wallis test for activity data2?
But then, how to correct for common confounders (age, sex...)?

Comment: A generalization of the K-W test that allows for covariate adjustment is the [proportional odds model](https://fharrell.com/post/rpo).  But the fact that you have dichotomized survival time into 2 arbitrary bins will ruin the entire analysis.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. We have individual survival data in months. Than if I understand well it would be better to generate  the Cox PH model for each variable?

Comment: I don't know why you said 'for each variable' but yes.  Note that time-to-event analysis assumes that all subjects had equal event surveillance opportunities so that time to censoring (time to last follow-up for which the subject is known to be event-free) is independent of impending risk of the event.

Comment: Thanks a lot! We have only 12 observations with survival time data, but I hope it will be fine to generate Cox model for measured enzymes ("variables")

Comment: I wouldn't do an analysis on a dataset with fewer than 15 events.